# Type "geometry" does not exists

Tags: postgresql, docker, gis, geospatial, postgis

I'm trying to construct a Docker image with a PostgreSQL and PostGIS database for one of our products. Although constructing the image (and container) isn't that hard and works, based on off [another PostGIS image](https://github.com/helmi03/docker-postgis). However when adding the ddl for constructing the database I'm running into issues.

I've constantly get the message: `ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist`. Because of this I've read and read on the internet and the main root seemed to be that I didn't properly initialize PostGIS Extensions. So I did that on a template table and running `SELECT postgis_full_version()` returns `POSTGIS="2.1.3 r12547" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.10.1, released 2013/08/26" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER` which seems to be alright. However still no dice...

Also after checking the available datatypes in the public schema via `\dT` I get that `geometry` type is available. That's why I'm a bit clueless here, since everything seems fine.

Anybody have any ideas how I can resolve this issue, or what I could look for?

Used versions:

- Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)
- PostgreSQL version: 9.3
- PostGIS version: 2.1

Edit: I'm trying again and tried to creating the extensions, than stopping PostgreSQL, running `ldconfig` (to reload lib's) and starting PostgreSQL again, but the same issue still persists.

Comment: What schema does it install postgis to? And is that schema listed in `show search_path;`?

Comment: Can you find the postgis/gdal/geos/proj4 extensions in the output of `ldconfig -v` ?

Comment: Which database did you install PostGIS in? Which database are you getting the error in?

Comment: @wildplasser libproj*.so, libgeos*.so, libgeos_c*.so and libgdal*.so are all available. I cannot seem to find any postgis*.so lib's.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' In a new database, based on off `template_postgis` that I've created and added the extensions upon. After trying to load the extension again, I get an error regarding that the extension was already loaded.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' yes, [see the PostGIS docs](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html). It is not a postgres type, as you had linked.

Comment: @AlexvandenHoogen why are you using `template_postgis`? You may have read old instructions. Why not the regular way: create an empty database then spatially enable it with `CREATE EXTENSION postgis`?

Comment: @MikeT: Well, duh. Maybe I should get offline for a while.

Comment: @MikeT Simply put, it is in the ddl that I have to use. Anyway, I have found the underlying problem and answer and will post that asap.

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured it out after quite some days of struggeling with this problem. It seems that after the schema creation, a `GRANT` was done from the created database to another user. Effectively not switching to that user was the problem.

What I've done now is ran the `create-user.sql` and `create-database.sql` files that were provided to me with the default postgres/postgis user and ran the rest with the new user that was created in the first sql file. After which the problems are gone. The search_path was the same for both users by the way, also the result of `PostGIS_full_version()` was exactly the same.

So, for future reference; if you create another user for your database, switch to that user after creating the database, otherwise PostGIS may have issues regarding it's datatypes.

Thank you all for your responses.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
psql my_database -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"
```

You have to create/enable the postgis extension.

Comment: Like I said in the OP, I already did that. Otherwise I wouldn't even get the PostGIS version back.

Comment: Did you run the postgis install with the ON_ERROR_STOP=1 flag?

Comment: Yes, but only got the same error: `ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist`, but only once instead of twice.